# How do forward fill missing value imputation for a PySpark dataframe with single column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with single column.

```
| Rank  
|----------
| 10
| 10
| null   
| null     
| 15
| null
| 20
| null     
| null     
| 15
| null   
| 10
```

I want to impute the missing values using forward fill like pandas ffill() function.

***Desired Output***

```
| Rank    
|----------
| 10
| 10
| 10   
| 10     
| 15
| 15
| 20
| 20     
| 20     
| 15
| 15   
| 10
```

Disclaimer: I have some some solutions in stackoverflow but they wont work when you only have a single column as input.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lag(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) and [lead](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lead(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) functions in spark.

lag and lead are used to only for getting one offset. Simple creating `udf` with a global variable should do a trick
Below is simple example

```
var PRV_RANK = 0f

import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(10f, 10f, Float.NaN, Float.NaN, 15f, Float.NaN, 20f, Float.NaN, Float.NaN, 15f, Float.NaN, 10f))
  .toDF("rank")

val forwardFill = udf((rank: Float) =>
{
  if (rank == null || rank.equals(Float.NaN)){
    PRV_RANK
  }
  else {
    PRV_RANK = rank
    rank
  }
})

data.withColumn("rankNew", forwardFill($"rank")).show()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you pls share the scala version of the code? I know you are good at Spark with scala :D

Comment: I have updated the answer, we could not do with the lag and lead for multiple null values.

Comment: No. I dont know how to convert this line "(rank == null || rank.equals(Float.NaN)" to python

Comment: you can do if rank is None or math.isnan(rank):

Comment: can you please accept as an answer if this worked for you ?

Comment: As recommended by you I used the math.isnan() function in the code given in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494002/how-to-check-in-python-if-cell-value-of-pyspark-dataframe-column-in-udf-function?noredirect=1#comment75989638_44494002

Comment: But I am still getting the same large error log I have listed in the question

Comment: This works perfectly in scala spark you should find a way to do in python.

Comment: import math
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, None), (1, 2, float(5)), (1, 3, float('nan')), (1, 4, None), (1, 5, float(10)), (1, 6, None)],
    ('session', "timestamp", "id"))



PRV_RANK = 0.0
def forwardfil(rank):
    
    if rank is None | math.isnan(rank):
        return PRV_RANK
    else:
        PRV_RANK = rank
        return rank        
    
forwardFill = F.udf(forwardfil, FloatType())

df.withColumn("ffill_new", forwardFill(df["id"])).show()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146480/discussion-between-shankar-koirala-and-ml-pro).