# How to check in Python if cell value of pyspark dataframe column in UDF function is none or NaN for implementing forward fill?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am basically trying to do a forward fill imputation. Below is the code for that.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1, None), (1,2, 5), (1,3, None), (1,4, None), (1,5, 10), (1,6, None)], ('session',"timestamp", "id"))

PRV_RANK = 0.0
def fun(rank):
    ########How to check if None or Nan?  ###############
    if rank is None or rank is NaN:
        return PRV_RANK
    else:
        PRV_RANK = rank
        return rank        

fuN= F.udf(fun, IntegerType())

df.withColumn("ffill_new", fuN(df["id"])).show()
```

I am getting weird error in the log.

Edit:
The question is related to how to identify null & nan in spark dataframe using python.

Edit:
 I am assuming the below line of code which checks for NaN & Null is causing the issue. So I have given the title accordingly for this question.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       df_na.withColumn("ffill_new", forwardFill(df_na["id"])).show()
>
> File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 318, in show
>       print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
>
> File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>
> File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o806.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 47.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 83, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 174, in main
>   File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 169, in
>   process   File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 106, in    File
>   "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 92, in
>      File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 70, in    File "", line 5,
>   in forwardfil UnboundLocalError: local variable 'PRV_RANK' referenced
>   before assignment
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2128)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2127)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2818)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2127)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2342)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 174, in main
>   File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 169, in
>   process   File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 106, in    File
>   "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 92, in
>      File "C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 70, in    File "", line 5,
>   in forwardfil UnboundLocalError: local variable 'PRV_RANK' referenced
>   before assignment
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   1 more

Comment: Is that the end of the stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for NaN in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python)

Comment: your `fuN` spelling is wrong

Comment: your question is still misleading. review it please

Answer (score 0):

```
df.withColumn("ffill_new", f.UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: x or 0, IntegerType())(df["id"])).show()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.